# How to replace data in the table using randomness under a certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

you need to replace the data in the table where supplier_code is different and invoice is the same

The problem is that the function selects 1 random value from all the supplier_code and applies it to all, but it is necessary that the function selects each time a random value from suppliers that are in the same invoice

```
create or alter view randNumber as 
Select RAND() as RND 

go
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION rndResult()
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RNDVALUE DECIMAL(18,10)
SELECT @RNDVALUE = RND
FROM randNumber
RETURN @RNDVALUE
END
go



Alter function NewInvoice() returns @table Table(supplier_code int, article nvarchar(30), invoic_number int, count int)
begin 
insert @table Select * from Contents_of_invoices 
DECLARE @value int;
SET @value = [dbo].[rndResult]();
Update @table
Set supplier_code  = (Select top 1 supplier_code  from ( select supplier_code  from Contents_of_invoices where invoice_number in (
    select invoice_number from (Select invoice_number from Contents_of_invoices
            group by invoice_number, supplier_code 
            having count(*) = 1) t1 group by invoice_number having COUNT(invoice_number)>1))as t1)
Where invoice_number in (select invoice_number from (Select invoice_number from Contents_of_invoices
            group by invoice_number, supplier_code 
            having count(*) = 1) t1 group by invoice_number having COUNT(invoice_number)>1)
return
end
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really not sure intend to do.

1. You're declaring @value as INT and then you're assigning it a DECIMAL that will be between 0 and 1

   `DECLARE @value int;`

   `SET @value = [dbo].[rndResult]();`
2. Then doing nothing with it at all.

If you need an INT pseudo-random number, I suggest you extrapolating the decimal value you returned from function rndResult.

3. when update @table, you update all the rows to update with TOP 1 results of the value that you got from the formula.

   `Set supplier_code  = (Select top 1`

I suggest you trying something like this

```
UPDATE toTouch
SET Supplier_code = new_supplierCode
FROM @table toTouch
/*you'll get a positive int, but keep in mind that there if you have many rows, there are high chances of duplicates when using CHECKSUM function */
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) new_supplierCode ) ca
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TOTOUCH
    INNER JOIN Contents_of_invoices 
        ON toTouch.invoice_number = Contents_of_invoices.invoice_number
    GROUP BY  Contents_of_invoices.invoice_number, Contents_of_invoices.supplier_code
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```